# Connections to my Raspberry PI SSH hang after a while

Tags: pi-2, ssh, ubuntu

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 B connected on the network with a static IP.

After a fresh reboot, I can connect to it smoothly and it just works: `ssh -A <ip> -p <port>`.

But after, let's say one day or more, the ssh request hangs and I don't know why. `ping <ip>` works fine, and it doesn't seem to be frozen completely.

The SSH connection simply hangs, tho.

How can I inspect this problem? What is the solution?

I'm running Ubuntu Mate on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step to analyze problems with ssh is to start the connection with verbose output:

```
~$ ssh -v user@<ip> -p <port>
```

You can improve verbosity of the debug output with `-vv` or `-vvv` but I suggest to start with `-v` to get an overview.

Try to connect without forwarding of the authentication agent connection (option `-A`), because it is unclear what the authentication agent is doing after a day.

Comment: I've just tried this, and it simply hangs: `Connecting to <host> port <port>`.

Comment: I have vncserver running on another port, and it has exactly the same problem. On the same pi I have a cronjob which sends system data every 10 minutes, and the CPU/Memory are low (because there is nothing expensive which runs on the machine). I can't understand why it would block these connections. I have another RPi around, configured exactly the same way and it works nicely.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Sorry, but I cannot help much more. I do not have any experience with Ubuntu Mate.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` connections timeout after a period of inactivity. This is unlikely to be the Pi, but the client timeout, although the network connection may timeout on inactivity.

You can set `ssh timeout` on the Pi, but you would be better to do this on your ssh client. This causes to client to send a keep alive message at regular intervals, and it will only disconnect if no response is received.

Alternatively just start a new `ssh` session!

Comment: Sorry, I am asking about new connections -- I am not leaving the SSH connection open one day, but I want to connect after one day again... and it just hangs.